# google analytics with rails 4 not sending data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I've tried using both a partial and the google-analytics-rails gem to include google analytics but I'm not getting any results. When I login to my account it says it's receiving data from the domain which is very unlikely since it said this before the code was actually pushed to the production server.

1st Attempt

layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'Figs.third_party_keys.google.analytics']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

and then I called this partial in the several layouts that are used across the application. Example below.

application.html.slim

```
= render '/layouts/google_analytics'
```

This gave no results so then I switched to the google-analytics-rails gem. I installed the gem and ran bundle and then in my production.rb I added the following line:

```
GA.tracker = "UA-xxxxxx-x" (I tried this with and without Figgy)
```

Feel like both of these are very simple tasks but not getting the results I'm looking for. Can it be something with trying to use Figgy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'Figs.third_party_keys.google.analytics']);
```

is suspect to me.  You're setting the `_setAccount` to the literal string `'Figs.third_party_keys.google.analytics'`.  Should this be:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', <%= Figs.third_party_keys.google.analytics %>]);
```

?